# How to read utf-8 encoded XML file in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, utf-8

Code was working fine & was getting values from `XML` file and was generating form of those values . I added encoding="UTF-8" to `XML` tag. And It is giving following warnings and error.
Thank you in adavance

```
Warning: DOMDocument::load(): parsing XML declaration: '?>' expected in file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/Urdu/english.xml, line: 1 in C:\

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): english.xml:1: parser error : parsing XML declaration: '?>' expected in C:\

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" encoding="UTF-8"?> in C:\xampp\htdocs\Urdu\getxmlform.php on line 64

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\Urdu\getxmlform.php on line 64

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to makeNodeField() must be an instance of SimpleXMLElement, boolean given, called in C:\ on line 66 and defined in C:\
```

Comment: Please show us how you write your xml tag

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"  encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: show us the code that generate the xml please. I'm guessing you get the parse error because you have short tags enabled.

Comment: i added the code which is reading xml file and instead of generating form giving these errors it was workinf fine before adding encoding to xml tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML declaration line is invalid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Move the underlined portion to the back and it will parse properly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

Comment: @Rozeena If you don't know the difference, you may just want to remove it entirely :)

Comment: "If an XML document can be read with no reference to external sources, it is said to be a stand-alone document."

Comment: i did but this file was assigned to me to do work on it . So i want to know the use of it if you can tell ?